# ASP.Net crashing on dotnet watch command

Tags: asp.net, dotnet-watch

I have been developing a website with ASP.Net and using "dotnet watch" to view progress as I go. Everything had been working fine, but today I updated VS and now whenever I make a change and save to view the change on the website, it gives me a "HTTP ERROR 500". I attached a screenshot from my powershell and have no idea what's going on. I am going to revert to the previous version for now so I can keep working, but if anyone has a soulution or knows whats going on please let me know.

Edit: I seem to have narrowed it down to editing `Layout.cshtml` while using `dotnet watch` to be causing the error. My other pages are fine but am concerned for when the website is deployed.

Error message from Visual Studio PowerShell:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HMK58AJSOF5Q", Request id "0HMK58AJSOF5Q:00000007": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      System.AggregateException: An error occurred while writing to logger(s). (Could not load type 'PortaBlu.Pages.Pages_Index+<ExecuteAsync>d__34#1' from assembly 'PortaBlu, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.) (Could not load type 'PortaBlu.Pages.Pages_Index+<ExecuteAsync>d__34#1' from assembly 'PortaBlu, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.)
       ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'PortaBlu.Pages.Pages_Index+<ExecuteAsync>d__34#1' from assembly 'PortaBlu, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
         at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule pModule, RuntimeType type, IRuntimeMethodInfo pCtor, Byte** ppBlob, Byte* pEndBlob, Int32* pcNamedArgs)
         at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.AddCustomAttributes(ListBuilder`1& attributes, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1 derivedAttributes)
         at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType)
         at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeMethodInfo method, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
         at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
         at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(MemberInfo element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
         at System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttributes[T](MemberInfo element, Boolean inherit)
         at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.TryResolveStateMachineMethod(MethodBase& method, Type& declaringType)
         at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.ToString(TraceFormat traceFormat, StringBuilder sb)
         at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.ToString(TraceFormat traceFormat)
         at System.Exception.get_StackTrace()
         at System.Exception.ToString()
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.SimpleConsoleFormatter.CreateDefaultLogMessage[TState](TextWriter textWriter, LogEntry`1& logEntry, String message, IExternalScopeProvider scopeProvider)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.SimpleConsoleFormatter.Write[TState](LogEntry`1& logEntry, IExternalScopeProvider scopeProvider, TextWriter textWriter)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.ConsoleLogger.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.<Log>g__LoggerLog|12_0[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, ILogger logger, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter, List`1& exceptions, TState& state)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.ThrowLoggingError(List`1 exceptions)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger`1.Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerMessage.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<Define>g__Log|0(ILogger logger, Exception exception)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsLoggerExtensions.UnhandledException(ILogger logger, Exception exception)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.BrowserRefreshMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
       ---> (Inner Exception #1) System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'PortaBlu.Pages.Pages_Index+<ExecuteAsync>d__34#1' from assembly 'PortaBlu, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
         at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule pModule, RuntimeType type, IRuntimeMethodInfo pCtor, Byte** ppBlob, Byte* pEndBlob, Int32* pcNamedArgs)
         at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.AddCustomAttributes(ListBuilder`1& attributes, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1 derivedAttributes)
         at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType)
         at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeMethodInfo method, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
         at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
         at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(MemberInfo element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
         at System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttributes[T](MemberInfo element, Boolean inherit)
         at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.TryResolveStateMachineMethod(MethodBase& method, Type& declaringType)
         at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.ToString(TraceFormat traceFormat, StringBuilder sb)
         at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.ToString(TraceFormat traceFormat)
         at System.Exception.get_StackTrace()
         at System.Exception.ToString()
         at System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(Object value)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.EventLogLogger.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.<Log>g__LoggerLog|12_0[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, ILogger logger, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter, List`1& exceptions, TState& state)<---
```

Comment: Dont think this has anything to do with  upgrading VS, I could be wrong though...  Try deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders from Windows Explorer, then try recompiling your project.

Comment: @mxmissile You're right, I uninstalled VS and reinstalled the same version because I realized it wasn't the update after uninstalling lol.

Comment: @mxmissile I deleted both bin and obj folders and recompiled, but still got error.

Comment: does `Pages/Index.cshtml` exist in your project?

Comment: Yes, I have index. I also wanted to test something and created a new project but it gave me the same error on both `index.cshtml` and `layout.cshtml` pages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a workaround for the time being. The Problem exists for `.NET SDK v6.0.400`.

1. Go to [.NET 6.0 SDK v6.0.302](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-6.0.302-windows-x64-installer) and download this version (previous version as of 9/6/2022). Type `dotnet --info` to see if it installed properly.
2. Inside of your project, add a new text file and label it `global.json`. Inside of the file, type this:

```
    {
      "sdk": {
        "version": "6.0.302"
      }
    }
```

[global.json reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json#examples)

Don't include `rollForward` as it would use the newest version which causes the problem.

The `global.json` file forces your project to use the specified version instead of the newest. If you downloaded a different version than `SDK v6.0.302`, then change the `global.json` accordingly.

Use this until Microsoft releases a patch to fix this bug. Hopes this helps!

Comment: Works for the time being. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still have the issue with SDK 6.0.302 :(

Comment: @Jerome2606 SDK v6.0.302 was just an example, just download and replace the version that you were previously using that worked.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution you can start the app in debug mode from Visual Studio (CTRL+F5) and have the "Hot reload on file save" checked.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a known bug, whose fix is already on the way. See [one of the related Github issues](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/43593#issuecomment-1229174109).

Comment: Great to hear, I was concerned it was a problem with my machine because I couldn’t find anything online about it. Thanks!